# Building and code signing an iPhone Application from the command line

Tags: iphone, gcc, command-line, llvm

I want to make my iPhone Apps in Emacs now, so without using Xcode at all.

How can I build and codesign my app from the command line (even through SSH)? I can't use xcodebuild as there is no Xcode project. Are there any tutorials which cover this? I want to compile them with GCC, and as soon as Developer Tools 4.0 come out, I want to compile them with LLVM.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

---

Is it also possible to debug it on the device without Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You could start with running a build through Xcode and then having a look at the build log. It contains all the commands and respective parameters used to build your project.

Then is should "just" be a matter of creating a make file using the same commands.